# How to move mesh symmetrical within geometry with each other

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have selected mesh which I want to be able to move closer and apart from each simultaneously if its possible without selecting the left side first, then the ride side. I tried individual origins but that scales the mesh and doesn't move it closer to each other.

PS: I don't need to mirror my mesh.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible except in Object mode, so you probably need to do it one after the other

Comment: Symmetry under active tools > Options is the closest to what you are asking

Comment: well of course if your object is symmetrical you can simply move your plane, go into the Mesh panel and Symmetrize, choose the axis in the Operator box  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable *Mesh Symmetry* on the proper axis.

[image]

Then you can select one side and move it and the other will follow.

[image]

Should work any time you're moving things around, it doesn't appear to work with any commands that create new vertices.  For example, I couldn't create the inset with this method, you'd have to start with a *Mirror Modifier* and apply it later, I suppose.

Comment: I guess it would be less confusing if you said "on the proper axis" and then use the proper axis in your screenshots as well ;) Sorry, just nitpicking. For the last paragraph: you're right, the mesh symmetry only works for translations, not anything that generates new vertices/faces. No matter if you want to do insets, loop cuts, knife cuts etc... so I am wondering: this object was created either with a _Mirror Modifier_ or by typing values to recreate it on the opposite side - so why blender breath doesn't keep using the modifier or doing it by hand for each side?

Comment: It is, I don't think I snapped camera or something.  Or I just spaced :D

Answer (score 1):

<s>As Moonboots says, it's not possible to do it in one fell swoop.</s>

See other answer: it is possible. Below solution is still valid, if a little more fiddly, however.

I'd suggest moving each one individually. To ensure symmetry, type in how much you're moving the first piece by, then make sure you move the opposite piece the same amount in the opposite direction.

To make this answer more full: You do this by pressing G to move the object, then X/Y/Z to constrain to a given axis, then type a number. Your piece will move by this distance (default in most recent Blender versions: metric metres) in the positive direction of that axis.

If you press the <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) key, it'll swap and move the object in the negative direction of that axis.